# SQL Order by meta table column including ones without meta entry

Tags: mysql, sql, laravel

I am using Laravel Query Builder. But I guess my issue is just SQL related.

I have a `responses` table and a `response_metas` table.

Where the `response_metas` table structure is:

```
 id   |   response_id    |    name    |    value
-----------------------------------------------------
```

All responses have some meta entries, some have the name=**email** meta.

Is there a way I can get:

> Responses having an email (meta) attached and ordered by this meta. As well as the ones without the name=email meta entry.

I can do a simple join:

```
DB::table('responses')
 ->join('response_metas', 'responses.id', '=', 'response_metas.response_id');
 ->where( 'response_metas.name', 'email')
 ->orderBy( 'response_metas.value', 'ASC' )
```

But obviously I am getting only the responses having an email meta. The goal is to get this result first. **But also the ones without this meta entry.**

Let me know if I can bring any clarification. I have done hours of failed tries using UNION, CASE, Conditions... None worked but I was likely not using them the right way.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: didn't get what you need in this ? do you want all data of response either it contain name = email or not   or something esle

Comment: Yes, all responses, having a meta email or not. Just the ones having a meta email appearing first.

Comment: use left join instead of join

Comment: that does not change anything :/ Thanks for the help though

Comment: could you do one more thing give some example like what data you have in both table what you desire and what you are getting now for better understanding

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<strike>If you want all the meta data for responses and ordered like email meta data should appear/sort first and then rest of the meta data then you can use conditional order by</strike>

```
DB::table('responses')
     ->join('response_metas', 'responses.id', '=', 'response_metas.response_id');
     ->where( 'response_metas.name', 'email')
     ->orderByRaw('response_metas.name = "email" DESC')
     ->orderBy( 'response_metas.value', 'ASC' )
```

The conditional clause if equivalent to below expression

```
->orderByRaw('CASE WHEN response_metas.name = "email" THEN 1 ELSE 0 END DESC')
```

To get all the responses either they have/don't have meta data for email you can use left join and put the conditions directly in join part

```
DB::table('responses')
    ->leftJoin('response_metas', function ($join) {
                $join->on('responses.id', '=', 'response_metas.response_id')
                     ->where( 'response_metas.name', 'email');
    })
    ->orderByRaw('CASE WHEN response_metas.value IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END DESC')
    ->orderBy( 'response_metas.value', 'ASC' );
```

Comment: Thanks, So am I supposed to only keep the join and the conditional orderByRow('CASE...') or something else? Because it does not seem to be working. I am getting everything but the ones having emails don't show up first.

Comment: @2Fwebd Can you add sample data for your tables ? so that i can also reproduce this issue

Comment: Thanks a lot Khalid, that helps a lot, I'm almost there. My only remaining problem is that I am getting one row per response_metas and not one row per response, does that make sense?

Comment: And if I groupBy('responses.id'), I'm getting only the first meta which is not the email.

Comment: @2Fwebd I have updated my answer not i got your point. Hope this helps