# Sorting on related table value (including elements without existing relation)

Tags: php, sorting, eloquent, slim-3

Lets say I have two tables: users and organisations

```
users:
id int,
name varchar,
type int,
deleted bool

organisations:
id int,
name varchar
deleted bool
```

and I want to sort organisations by user of type 1 name. I know that when I want to sort by relation value I have to use join:

```
$organisationsModel -> join( 'users', 'organisations.id', '=', 'users.organisationId', 'left' ) 
    -> select( 'organisations.*', 'users.name as userName' ) 
    -> where( 'users.type', 1 ) 
    -> where( 'users.deleted', 0 )
    -> orderBy( 'userName', 'ASC );
```

but it only shows organisations that have user of type 1 (with deleted set to 0), and my question is: can I modify this query to also return values without proper user connected with it?

Comment: What is your expected output you want all the users whether type is 1 or not  but sort users with type 1 first and then others ?

Comment: I want to always recive all organisations sorted by user (type 1, deleted 0) name BUT when organisation does not have proper user attached to it, it should emulate user name as empty string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a left join with additional joining clauses in order to get all organizations, To order the results you can use conditional order by clause

```
 $organisationsModel->leftJoin('users', function ($join) {
                                    $join->on('organisations.id', '=', 'users.organisationId')
                                         ->where( 'users.type', 1)
                                         ->where( 'users.deleted', 0 );
                    })
                    ->select( 'organisations.*', 'users.name as userName' ) 
                    ->orderByRaw('CASE WHEN users.type = 1 AND users.deleted = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END DESC')
                    ->orderBy( 'userName', 'ASC );
```

[Another similar problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47667037/sql-order-by-meta-table-column-including-ones-without-meta-entry/47667808#47667808)

Comment: THANKS MAN! I've changed your code a little bit (fe. first join is unnecessary) but it works!